# Effects of using mock to rebuild packages on Centos 6.4

Tags: centos6

Currently I have rebuild ossec on centos 6.4 using mock. Will this have any effect on the stability of the os and also with regards to any other updates on the system? Any chance to cause crashes?

Comment: If you only rebuild without updating on the system there would be any effect

Comment: @Yes I rebuild and install on the system. My worry on the stability ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mock` builds packages in a dedicated `chroot` environment.  It does not make any changes to your live system.  `mock` only creates files within the `/var/lib/mock` and `/var/cache/mock` directories.

Comment: is it safe to rebuild ossec back on my centos 6.4 due to I am being reluctant to install latest version of mysql due to stability as to what ossec propose too.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question and I'm not familiar with ossec.  It doesn't look like *installing* ossec would have an impact on the *stability* of your system, although any intrusion detection system that supports "active response" could have an operational impact on your environment.  If you have questions about ossec, you should probably open a new question that focuses on that rather than on the question of rebuilding things with mock.

Comment: @My question is more on is it ok to rebuilt ossec using mock and the impact on the on os in future thats is why my question actually. I have rebuild and I can see the results of the rebuild and I go into the var/lib/mock and even manage to yum install. After installing can I like remove those files?